# Deixar input invisivel em SAPUI5

Tags: erp

Estou começando a trabalhar com SAPUI5, e eu precisava deixar um input de uma formulário invisível.

Nessa tela terá um input para o usuário colocar o login, e do lado um input onde aparecerá o nome do usuário a quem pertence aquele login.
O segundo input so pode aparecer se tiver um login preenchido no primeiro

Segue código

view/App.view.xml

```
xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="Aproval">
            <content>
                <IconTabBar id="idTopLevelIconTabBar">
                    <items>

                        <IconTabFilter id="layouts" text="Inicio">

                            <l:Grid defaultSpan="L9 M7 S12" width="auto">
                                <l:content>
                                    <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormChange354" minWidth="1024"
                                        maxContainerCols="2" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                                        title="aproval" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3"
                                        emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
                                        class="editableForm">
                                        <f:content>



                                            <Label text="Login de" />
                                            <HBox>
                                                <Input value="" id="login" />


                                                <Input value="" id="nome">
                                                </Input>
                                            </HBox>
                                            <Label text="Para" />
                                            <HBox>
                                                <Input value="" id="loginPara" />


                                                <Input value="" id="nomePara">
                                                </Input>
                                            </HBox>
                                            <Label text="Data de" />
                                            <DatePicker dateValue="" placeholder="Insira a data"
                                                id="datade" />


                                            <Label text="Data até" />
                                            <DatePicker dateValue="" placeholder="Insira a data"
                                                id="datapara" />

                                            <Label />
                                            <Button type="Accept" press="submit" text="Submit"></Button>

                                        </f:content>
                                    </f:SimpleForm>
                                </l:content>
                            </l:Grid>
                        </IconTabFilter>
                    </items>
                </IconTabBar>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

## index.html

OpenSAP - Developing Web Apps with SAPUI5

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{    "opensap.myapp": "./"   }'> 
      </script>
<script> 
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {    sap.ui.xmlview({     viewName: "opensap.myapp.view.App"    }).placeAt("content");   });  </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alguem me ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um pouco tarde, porem a quem seja util. Voce pode usar o **setVisible** do **sap.ui.core.control**

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.13/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#setVisible

No xml ficaria assim:

```
<Input value="" id="login" change:"onChange" />

<Input value="" id="nome" setVisible=false/>
```

Observe que criei um manipulador de eventos para o input login, no controller ficaria assim:

```
onChange: function(oEvent){
    var login = this.byId("login").getValue();
    if(login){
        this.byId("nome").setVisible(true);
        this.byId("nome").setValue(login);
    }
}
```